# Convert Django urlpatterns to dictionary

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I'm working on a new Django project and building an API using the Django REST Framework. I'm trying to enable a view that is **only accessible when `DEBUG=True`** that will serialize the current urlpatterns and send them back as JSON so front end developers can work with it.

I'm looking for a clean way to do it. I can iterate through each pattern, but a pattern could potentially have an unlimited number of subpatterns, so I need some method that can handle that.

Is there something built in for this? Any way besides just brute forcing the URLs? I can write it from scratch, but there must be a better way since the Django 404 page contains this information. I'll dig through that source code as well.

Note: Complexity and security are not an issue since this entire view will only be available when the system is in `DEBUG`.

The result I'm looking for is something like:

```
{
    "^admin/": [
                  "^$ [name='index']",
                  "^admin/ ^login/$ [name='login']",
                  "^admin/ ^logout/$ [name='logout']",
                  ...
               ],
    "^auth/": [ ... ]
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: [Django admin docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/admindocs/) already do something very similar. Check it out!

Comment: Thanks! Definitely a more complete option (see my answer), but was looking for a method that doesn't require adding more code to other areas. Will consider this for the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, `dir()`, and `pdb`, I came up with a solution. It uses a recursive strategy to search through the URLS until it finds a RegexURLPattern, and terminates there. This works for my URL setup but I'm not sure how robust it would be for complex url configurations. Still interested in hearing other ideas!

```
def recursively_build__url_dict(d, urlpatterns):
    for i in urlpatterns:
        if isinstance(i, RegexURLResolver):
            d[str(i.__dict__['_regex'])] = {}
            recursively_build__url_dict(
                d[str(i.__dict__['_regex'])], i.url_patterns
            )

        elif isinstance(i, RegexURLPattern):
                d[str(i.regex.pattern)] = i.callback.__name__
```

Edit: I've turned this into a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jamiecounsell/7956fd89869c327a0310)